# Calculate transformation matrix from three 3D points

Tags: c++, opencv, coordinate-systems, affinetransform, coordinate-transformation

I have a 3D coordinate system of which I track the three outer points with a 3D camera.
So I have three points in (x,y,z) space.
Next frame I track these three points again.
I use the first three points as initial situation. Now I need to draft a transformation matrix  that gives me the translation, rotation and scaling of the second 3 points, in comparison with the initial position.

Now I do not really know how to do this.
Is there a way to directly make the  the transformation matrix, or do I first have to work out the translation, rotation and scale matrix and than make a transformation matrix of these three?

I work in c++ with opencv and qt. 
Somebody got any suggestions? I do not necessarily need a full working example, anything that can get me on my way is appreciated.

Thanks! 
J

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) looks pretty nice (what you are looking for is called an **affine** transform)!

Comment: This looks like it, except that it is a tutorial for 2D point, I have 3D point. I notice that the functions in opencv are rather for 2D than for 3D. I will try to make a solution based on 2D, but perhaps you know a solution for 3D points?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the transformation from old positions to new positions as a system of equations, where the unknowns are the elements of the matrix. Solving this system will give you the matrix.